# Proof of matrixnorm relative to one-norm

Tags: analysis, proof-verification, operator-theory, normed-spaces

> Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ a $d \times d$-matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ with norm $\|\cdot\|_1$. Proof: $$\|A\|= \max_\limits{j=1,...,d} \sum_\limits{i=1}^d |a_{ij}|$$

Let $\|x\|_1=1$ and $Ax=y$: $\|Ax\|_1= \sum_\limits{i=1}^d |y_i| = \sum_\limits{i=1}^d \left(\big\vert\sum_\limits{j=1}^d a_{ij}x_j\big\vert\right) \le   \sum_\limits{i=1}^d \sum_\limits{j=1}^d |a_{ij}| \cdot |x_j|\le \left(\max_\limits{j=1,...d} \sum_\limits{i=1}^d |a_{ij}|\right) \cdot \underbrace{\big(\sum_\limits{j=1}^d |x_j|\big)}_{=\|x\|_1=1}$

I hope the argumentation is right. Now I have to show that $\|Ax\|_1 \ge \max_\limits{j=1,...d} \sum_\limits{i=1}^d |a_{ij}|$ but unfortunately I haven't no good idea. Any hints?

Comment: You need to find $x$ such that every inequality is in fact an equality and you will be done.

Comment: ahh okay. So if $x_j=e_j, j=1,...,d$, a standard basis vector, there is an equality, right?

Comment: Almost, you have to choose a particular $j$.

Comment: Sorry, I dont know, it doesnt make sense for me.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** You have to find a vector $x$ such that $||Ax||_1 = \max_\limits{j=1,...,d} \sum_\limits{i=1}^d |a_{ij}|$

Let $j_0$ such that:

$\max_\limits{j=1,...,d} \sum_\limits{i=1}^d |a_{ij}| = \sum_\limits{i=1}^d |a_{ij_0}|$
Let $e$ the vector such that $e_j = 1$ if $j=j_0$ and $e_j = 0$ otherwise.

Now compute $||Ae||_1$.